# How to limited drag/drop (jquery sortable)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My code is like this :

```
  $("ol.example").sortable({
      group: "example",
  });

    $("ol.simple_with_drop").sortable({
    group: 'no-drop',
    handle: 'i.icon-move',
    onDragStart: function ($item, container, _super) {
      // Duplicate items of the no drop area
      if(!container.options.drop)
        $item.clone().insertAfter($item);
      _super($item, container);
    }
  });

  $("ol.simple_with_no_drop").sortable({
    group: 'no-drop',
    drop: false
  });

  $("ol.simple_with_no_drag").sortable({
    group: 'no-drop',
    drag: false
  });
```

Demo & complete code is like this : https://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/vs4zggjf/

I want to make to be like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrYwC.jpg. So,I would like to add some conditions. Customers can only drag in room type. While room type can not drag to the customer. whether it can be done? I have tried but did not succeed.

I take from here : https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/#connected

Thank you

Comment: Whether this question too difficult to answer?